DevOps, Running Azure Pool, AzureStaticWebApp0 getting 'Docker: command not found'
Here is the relevant part of my pipeline:
pool:
  name: (this value matches my pool in Azure screen print below)
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    api_location: 'api'
    output_location: '/output'
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)

Here is my error:
/usr/bin/bash /mnt/vss/_work/_tasks/AzureStaticWebApp_.../0.247.3/launch-docker.sh
/mnt/vss/_work/_tasks/AzureStaticWebApp_.../0.247.3/launch-docker.sh: line 1: docker: command not found

I get what it's telling me, (I think).   I think it's telling me that docker is not there.  However, I'm running an azure pool, which should have docker.   So I don't see what I'm missing here.
My Azure Pool:

